# CANCAN undefined method `user_type?' for "admin":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, rubygems, cancan

here is my problem:

I'm using cancan gem. I think all is set up well, except for one thing, that produces `undefined method 'user_type?' for "admin":String`.

Here is my ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new # guest user
       if user.user_type? :admin
         can :manage, :all
       # [code code code code commented to find more easily the problem]
        else
          can :read, :all
        end
  end
end
```

My user.rb

```
require 'digest/sha2'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #definisco i ruoli
  ROLES = %w[admin client banned]
  default_scope :order => 'user' [...]
```

I can't figure out what I have to modify. Why `if user.user_type? :admin` don't check the current user attribute? Thanks a lot for your attention!

UP: Ok, I read around that cancan need method "current_user" declared in application controller. Now I work on it. News, soon.

Comment: Where have you defined the user_type? method ?

Comment: Where are you checking for authorization? What controller? (if it is a controller) Please paste that code too. It's because somehow, the `user` variable being passed to `CanCan` is a string with value `"admin"` - you want the `user` to actually be a `User` instance.

Comment: solved!!!

into ability.rb

if user.user_type == "admin"

In application controller I add

def current_user
      @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) 
end


THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this.I think it is better approach.

Seed roles into DB.

And in application helper paste this code.

```
def is_admin?(user)
  admin_role = Role.find(:first, :conditions => ["name = ?", "admin"])
  return user.roles.include?(admin_role)
end
```

And then in ability call like

```
            class Ability
             include CanCan::Ability
             def initialize(user)
               user ||= User.new # guest user
                 if is_admin?(user)
                   can :manage, :all
                    # [code code code code commented to find more easily the problem]
                 else
                   can :read, :all
                 end
             end
           end
```

And it will work fine.......